# Unable to see the new post made from my android project from chrome browser

Tags: android, post, rx-java, retrofit2

I am trying to make a post following this [link](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/sending-data-with-retrofit-2-http-client-for-android--cms-27845).

The app runs successfully but I am unable to see the new post from chrome browser or postman.

The interface code:

```
public interface APIService {

@POST("/posts")
@FormUrlEncoded
rx.Observable<Post> savePost(@Field("title") String title,
                             @Field("body") String body,
                             @Field("userId") Integer userId);

@PUT("/posts/{id}")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<Post> updatePost(@Path("id") long id,
                      @Field("title") String title,
                      @Field("body") String body,
                      @Field("userId") long userId);
}
```

Why is this so?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why should you see a request made by your Android app in Chrome or Postman?

Comment: @fjc I have made a new post, so I want to see if it has happened. Basically I am learning to send object to server from my android project, so,  I am curious to see if my post has been successful.

Comment: Your Android HTTP request does not normally pass through Chrome or Postman. You will need to look on the server-side whether or not the request comes through or add some logging in your app.

Comment: @fjc You were right probably, so I followed this link : https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ to start a remote server that I can access.: http://localhost:3000. But now when I run the app with this as baseurl, I am unable to POST the data but GET works. Why do you think so?

Comment: What does it give as an error message for POST?

Comment: @fjc Th error says:"W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:3000"

Comment: You are trying to connect from your phone to your computer. When you use "localhost", that is a connection from your phone to your phone. This cannot work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178201/discussion-between-eswar-and-fjc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was that the "id" that I was passing was clashing with an already existing "id" in the end point. It was a duplicate.

I changed the "id" to another id number and the problem was solved.